# How do i set values based on other values when database opens

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to get the status of my jobs to change automatically when the database opens.

```
If Me.STATUS = 6 And Me.UPDATED_TIME = Date - 1 Then
    Me.STATUS = 2
Else
End If
```

that is my current code however it doesn't seem to be working...
help please!

Comment: Please specify what's working, and what isn't working. This seems to be code that should be ran on a form. That's an unlikely way to update data. You usually use update queries for that.

Comment: That is probably a major issue. I am very new to access and am playing around and had the idea. that whole thing doesnt work. where would i put this code or how would i set it up

Comment: That's a very broad question. You shouldn't use vba for this at all, but an update query. Start by reading in on those

Comment: Thank you, I had ZERO idea! that is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

as explained by Erik von Asmuth, vba was not the proper way to complete the task I was wanting. Below is the link to where I found the how to on an "Update Query"
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-run-an-update-query-9dddc97c-f17d-43f4-a729-35e5ee1e0514